# How to use FILESTREAM in MVC 5 and EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

This might be a silly question but I got confuse on the use of FileStream.

At first I thought FileStream is just an System.IO implementation for reading and saving files but there is also FILESTREAM for MSSQL or Database Storage.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

My problem here is I would like to implement FILESTREAM on my application since I am just going to store profilepictures but what I dont get is the implementation part.

There are no examples or mention on how to use it in Entity Framework like what Filetype to be use or do I need to install a nuget. If I search for implementation of FileStream what I get is System.IO which does not have any reference for saving in database since it is use for file system

I am so confused. Please help.

Comment: When I do a google search for `entity framework filestream` I find plenty of results (which admittedly, all say it's not directly supported, but many of which do suggest workarounds). None of them seem to relate to the `System.IO.FileStream` class.

Comment: I already read most of the site but yeah its most workarounds, and most of them are old (2 - 3 years). I am actually expecting an easy implementation but I guess from my 4 hours research I conclude there is none yet

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that SQL Server FileStream is an over engineering solution for just keeping users avatars on oyour server. You can easily store the avatars on your server as files in some particular folder with having a corresponding record in your avatars reference table that keep the file path or store the avatar as a `VARBINARY` field in an avatars table.

*Storing avatars as files seems to me a more straight forward solution because later on you can add an url of the file in some `<img/>` in purpose to display the avatar.*

As for the rest I would suggest the following:

1) In your MVC view please reffer a model like that

```
public class AvatarModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase AvatarFile { get; set; }
}
```

2) Start your Avatar View with the following statement

```
 using (
    Html.BeginForm("Avatar", "UserManagement", FormMethod.Post, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } )
    )
```

3) In the View  define the inputs and submit button

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserId" value="@Model.UserId" />
<input type="file" id="AvatarFile" />

<button type="submit"/>
```

4) In your UserManagement controller implement the following method

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Avatar")]
public ActionResult AvatarPost(AvatarModel model)
{
...
}
```

5) in the body of the method you will acess your file over the `model` argument
`model.AvatarFile`. The object `model.AvatarFile` gives you two possibilities either save as a file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx or you can read the file as a stream https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx convert it to a `byte[]` and then assign the byte array to a particular model of your entityt framework model.

Please keep in mind that by uploading the file you should keep the POST message <=64 Kbytes. In other case you will have customize your application config and the config of IIS on your server.
But 64 Kbytes should be enought for a avatat isn't it?

Comment: This is a good implementation and will bookmark this for future use but I am more looking forward on utilize the FILESTREAM feature. Yes your right that 64kb will be enough for an avatar and can be use in my application but I want to learn FILESTREAM so that maybe in my other release I can utilize it for storing documents or bigger pictures.